# How to add an admin panel to a react project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, admin, react-admin

I need to create a way for a person without programming skills to add news to the site, the site is already ready, but I am looking for technologies to add an admin panel.

I learned about react-admin, but all examples with this library are for dashboards.

Can you give me an advice, what technology should i use?

Comment: You could google "CMS". I heard Contentful (https://www.contentful.com/) for this purpose but don't have any personal experiences with it.

Comment: Instead of going down the road of creating a content management system(CMS) using JavaScript, I suggest you use technologies like WordPress. Makes adding News to your website easier.